# Consecutive integers 8p, 9q, 10r: search for small solution sets (p,q,r) other than (1,1,1).

Tags: elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

The context: I want to show how prime factorisation patterns repeat along the number line. I've taken three consecutive integers, the first containing 2^3, the second 3^2, the third 5^1. Taking respective multiples p, q, r, this gives me a set of equations and a set of conditions, namely neither 2 nor 3 nor 5 can divide any of them. I've also found that p, q, r must all end in a '1'. What's the most efficient way to search for a solution set other than (1, 1, 1)?,

Comment: Write down all solutions for the linear Diophantine equation $-8p+9q=1$, and then solve $9q+1=10r$. Then you have infinitely many solutions, e.g. $(p,q,r)=(91,81,73)$. Indeed, then $8p,9q,10r$ are consecutive integers, namely $728,729,730$.

Comment: Hint: $ $ let $\,\bar p = p-1,\,\ \bar q = q-1,\,\ \bar r = r-1.\,$ Then

$$\begin{align} &1+8p = 9q\, = 10r-1\\[.2em]
\iff &\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 8\bar p = 9\bar q = 10\bar r  =: \,m\\[.2em]
\iff &\ \ 8,9,10\mid m\\[.2em]
\iff &\ \  m = 360n,\,\ {\rm by\,\ lcm}(8,9,10)=360\\[.2em]
 \iff &\ \ (\bar p,\bar q,\bar r) = (45n,40n,36n)
\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

Comment: So the decrementing shift reduces it to the [lcm universal property:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2322544/242) $\,a,b,c\mid m\iff [a,b,c]\mid m.\,$ To calculate the lcm note $\,[9,[8,10]] = [9,2[4,5]] = [9,40] = 360\,$ where we used basic lcm properties: $\,(a,b)=1\Rightarrow [a,b]=ab,\, $ and lcm is [associative,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/738278/242) and the [lcm distributive law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242). Or we can compute the [lcm via prime factorizations](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/627140/242)

Comment: Note that I require the exponents concerned to be no bigger than the ones I gave, hence my condition that 2, 3, 5 must divide none of p, q, r.

Comment: $p,\color{#c00}q,r = 1\!+\!45n,\,1\!+\!\color{#c00}{40}n,\,1\!+\!36n\,$ are all coprime to $30\!\iff\! 1\!+\!n\,$ is coprime to $30,\,$ e.g. $\,\color{#c00}q = 1\!+\!\color{#0a0}{10}(4n)\,$ is coprime to $\,\color{#0a0}{10},\,$ and it is coprime to $3\!\iff\! 1=(3,1\!+\!\color{#c00}{40}n) = (3,1\!+\!\color{#c00}{1}n),\,$ by $\,\color{#c00}{40\equiv 1}\pmod{\!3}\ \ $

Answer (score -1):

If $9|(8p+1)$ then you can prove that $ 8p\equiv -1(mod9)$ so $p\equiv 1 (mod9)$.

Similarly if $10|(9q+1)$ then try and prove that $q\equiv 1(mod 10)$.

If $10|(8p+2)$ $\implies 5|(4p+1)$ then $p\equiv 1(mod 5)$. Since 9, 5 are coprime, you can write that $p\equiv 1(mod 45)$. Hence,
$$p=45x+1, q=40x+1, r=36x+1$$ form a solution for natural x.  I derived q and r via $q=\frac{8p+1}{9}$ and $r=\frac{9q+1}{10}$.

Comment: Incorrect. Easier: by a shift it immediately reduces to an $\,\rm lcm$ - see my prior comment on the question.

Comment: @BillDubuque which part is wrong exactly? I haven’t done number theory for about two years so this answer was kind of a guess. Can you please point out the line which I should correct?

Comment: Your $nx$'s should be half that, e.g. $\,p = 45x+1\,$ for the general solution. Maybe you took the moduli product instead of their lcm.

Comment: Isn’t the lcm of 9 and 10 equal to 90? @BillDubuque

Comment: You didn't $\color{#c00}{\rm cancel\ 2}$ here: $\,10\mid 8p\!+\!2\!\!\!\overset{\large \color{#c00}{\div 2\!}}\iff 5\mid 4p\!+\!1\iff p\equiv 1\pmod{\!5},\,$ so your claimed solution $\,p\equiv 1\pmod{\!10}\,$ is missing the solutions $\,p\equiv 6\pmod{\!10},\,$ e.g. $\,p=6.\ \ $

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks @BillDubuque