# number theory lcm

Tags: elementary-number-theory

prove if $a, b ,c$ are positive integers, then $lcm(a,lcm(b,c))=lcm(a,b,c)=lcm(lcm(a,b),c)$
$lcm$ is least common multiple
My thought is to show that they have common divisors but not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Observe that any common multiple of $a$ and $b$ is a multiple of $\text{lcm}(a,b)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254704/prove-that-textlcm-textlcma-b-c-textlcma-textlcmb-c

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If the highest exponents of prime $p$ in $a,b,c$ be $A,B,C$ respectively.

WLOG $A\ge B\ge C$

Now the highest exponents of prime $p$ in lcm$(a,b,c)$ will be max$(A,B,C)=A$

lcm$(a,$lcm$(b,c))=$max$(A,$max$(B,C))=$max$(A,B)=A$

lcm$($lcm$(a,b),c))=$max$(A,C)=A$

This holds true any prime that divides at least one of $a,b,c$

Comment: Would finding the greatest common multiple be the same proof?

Comment: @Lord, definitely