# Does lcm of multiple numbers also divide any common multiple of these numbers?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

I know that this is true for two numbers, but does this also hold for more than two? I.e. if $m$ is a common multiple of several numbers $n_1, \ldots , n_k$, does it hold that lcm$(n_1,\ldots,n_k)$ divides $m$? If so, how would one go about proving that? Maybe considering pairs of numbers of the set?

Comment: What is the definition of lcm$(n_1,\dots,n_k)$?

Comment: Hint : Divide $m$ by the lcm of the numbers with remainder and use that the remainder divides as well all the numbers. This leads to an easy proof by contradiction.

Comment: Yes, of course.  fwd asked "What is the definition of $lcm(n_1, ..., n_k)$?".   If you know that, and you should if you ask about "lcm", that   should be obvious.

Comment: @user247327 That lcm is the least common multiplier does not immediately show that every common multiple must be a multiple of the lcm, just that it must be larger , if it is not the lcm.

Comment: @Peter Okay, so if $l$ is the lcm of the numbers, then by euclidean division we have $m=lk+r$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and a remainder $r$. Assuming that $l$ does not divide $m$ yields $r>0$. But then $r$ is a common multiple of the numbers, and smaller than $l$, which is the contradiction? Would this be the proof?

Comment: Exactly! You got it ! Congratulations !

Comment: This really makes sense, thank you so much!

Comment: Most proofs for two integers also work for any finite number of integers, e.g. see the linked dupes. Alternatively use [associativity of LCM](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/254996/242) to reduce to (compositions) of  LCM of two arguments

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Consider the prime factor decomposition and note that the exponent $p(x)$ of a prime $p$ dividing the lcm $x$ of numbers $x_1,...,x_k$ is given by $\max \{p(x_1), ... , p(x_k)\}$. What can you say about $p(y)$ for a common multiple $y$ of $x_1,...,x_k$?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}\lcm(n_1,\dots,n_k)$ is the positive generator of the (principal) ideal of common multiples of $n_1,\dots,n_k$:
$$n_1\mathbf Z\cap\dots\cap n_k\mathbf Z=\lcm(n_1,\dots,n_k)\mathbf Z,$$
so the answer is obvious.