# Show that $lcm$ is associative via nesting the maximum-function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I found some proofs for the claim that for natural numbers $a,b,c$ it holds that
$$
\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b),c) 
=
\operatorname{lcm}(a,\operatorname{lcm}(b,c)).
$$

I wonder whether one could show it this way: Let $\mathbb P$ be the set of prime numbers.
Now let
$$
a = \prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb P}p^{\alpha_p},
b = \prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb P}p^{\beta_p},
c = \prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb P}p^{\gamma_p}
$$
be the unique prime decompositions.
It is
$$\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)
=
\prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb P}p^{\max\{\alpha_p, \beta_p\}}.
$$

Then it is
$$\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b),c)
=
\prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb P}p^{\max\{\max\{\alpha_p, \beta_p\},\gamma_p\}}.
$$

And here I have the feeling I am missing an intermediate step, since nothing should be argumented with "it is obvious". So, am I maybe missing a valid argumented that these max relations can be nested this way?

Comment: Your argument is fine.  It reduces associativity for lcm to associativity of max.  Will you also need to prove that?  You could also just use the proof that in a general lattice, $a \vee (b\vee c) = (a\vee b)\vee c$.  Argue by the definition of "least upper bound".

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you. No, I won't proof the associativity of max. My problem was that one could argue "where does the nested max come from?".

Comment: It is just basic substitution. Given the formula you used for lcm(a,b) in terms of their prime factorisation, you are just using it again but with the prime factorisation of lcm(a,b) and c substituted instead of a and b. I don't think it needs further steps, though an extra connecting sentence wouldn't go amiss. Something like "Applying the same formula to the pair of integers lcm(a,b) and c results in:". When you then do lcm(a,lcm(b,c)) I think you can skip all the steps and go directly there.

Comment: See the simple proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/254996/242)  that max is associative, using its universal property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is written with the understanding that the question asks how to justify the nesting of $\text{max}\{.\}$ operators. In this case, the title should be changed.

If you let $L=\text{lcm}(a, b)$ and
$$L=\prod_{p\in P}p^{\lambda_p}$$
where $\lambda_p=\text{max}\{\alpha_p, \beta_p\}$, you have:
$$\text{lcm}\left(\text{lcm}(a, b), c\right)=\text{lcm}(L, c),$$
which is a stanadard LCM of two integers.

---

Furthermore, your nested $\{\text{max}\}$-es can be denested by observing the following:

Suppose you have the integers (or any real numbers really) $a$, $b$ and $c$ and you are interested in the value of $M=\text{max}\{\text{max}\{a, b\}, c\}$. Well, if $c$ is the largest of the three, clearly $M=\text{max}\{a, b, c\}=c$. Otherwise, $c$ is irrelevent and we can write:
$$M=\text{max}\{\text{max}\{a, b\}, c\}=\text{max}\{a, b\}=\text{max}\{a, b, c\},$$
since $c<a$ or $c<b$.

Comment: Thank you. I think your first paragraph is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque I appologize for posting a duplicate answer, I was unaware of the existance of the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set of positive integers, with partial order "$a$ divides $b$".  Then "least upper bound" for that order is "greatest common divisor". If we prove this in the setting of a partially ordered set, using definition of "least upper bound", then we (a) get a more general result and (b) do not need "unique factorization".

In a partially ordered set, let $a \vee b$ denote the least upper bound of $\{a,b\}$ when it exists.  We claim: if the four least upper bounds mentioned exist, then
$$
a \vee (b\vee c) = (a\vee b)\vee c
\tag1$$

*Proof.* Compute
$$
a \le a \vee b \le (a\vee b)\vee c
\tag2$$
Next
$$
b \le (a\vee b)\le(a\vee b)\vee c\quad\text{and}\quad c\le (a\vee b)\vee c
$$
so
$$
b\vee c \le (a\vee b)\vee c
\tag3$$
Note $(2)$ and $(3)$ say that $(a\vee b)\vee c$ is an upper bound for $\{a,b\vee c\}$, so it beats the *least* upper bound:
$$
a \vee (b\vee c) \le (a\vee b)\vee c
\tag4$$
Now we repeat this for the other direction.
$$
a \le a \vee (b\vee c) \quad\text{and}\quad  b \le (b\vee c) \le a \vee (b\vee c)
$$
so
$$
a\vee b \le a \vee (b\vee c)
\tag5$$
and
$$
c \le b\vee c \le a \vee (b\vee c)
\tag6$$
From $(5)$ and $(6)$ we get
$$
(a\vee b)\vee c \le a \vee (b\vee c)
\tag7$$
Finally, from $(4)$ and $(7)$, we conclude
$$
a \vee (b\vee c) = (a\vee b)\vee c
\tag1$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).